# emacs: abort keyboard macro if point not on regex

Tags: emacs

I am not an emacs lisp hacker, but a very frequent user of emacs keyboard macros, especially for manipulating long data files.  about 1-in-20 times, I screw up.  my macro edits when it really should not.  what I think I would need is something like

```
M-x check-regex-on-point
```

which would abort (ring the door bell) when the cursor is not on something specific that I would think that it should be on at this moment (e.g., a number, an alpha string, a comma, etc.)

is there a package or function for such tasks?

Comment: Are you talking about using Lisp macros or keyboard macros? The question is unclear to me, even aside from this question. Just what are you trying to do, and what have you tried so far (e.g. code or sequence of actions)?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this (a wild guess)? `M-: (unless (looking-at-p REGEXP) (keyboard-quit))`

Comment: thx, drew.  just clarified I mean keyboard macro, not elisp macro.  with your elisp code, the rest was easy.  do you want to post the answer and me check it, or should I do this?

Comment: Please post the answer yourself, with whatever solution you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun check-regex-on-point (x)
  "abort keyboard macro if not at the right spot"
  (interactive "sregex: ")
  (unless (looking-at-p x) (keyboard-quit))
  )
```

based on Drew's points in his comments above.